# How to add each element in a list to a new row in React table

Tags: reactjs

I'm super new to React and was wondering if there's a good and simple way to iterate through a list, and add each element in the list to a new row? For instance, for list:

`name = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

Eventually I want the table to have only one column and four rows:

| Name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data=['A','B','C','D'];

function Table() {
  return (
    <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>row</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       {
        data.map(item=>(<tr key={item}><td>{item}</td></tr>))
       }
       </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Table/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

It is so easy. Needs to read about React.

Comment: Nice usage of `<thead>`. It's quite helpful in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can map over your data when rendering.

```js
return(
   <table>
   {name.map(rowName => 
       <tr key={rowName}>
           <td>{rowName}</td>
       </tr>
   } 
   </table>
)
```

You need to add a key to each component in the list so react knows when to rerender it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your answer. However I was wondering if there's a way to do this while not adding a key to each component?

Comment: You need a key, see here: https://rescript-lang.org/docs/react/latest/arrays-and-keys

Comment: @LCL, You need to add a `key`. otherwise, it will warn in runtime. Adding `key` with a unique id is the normal practice

Comment: You could map the array with index, and use the index as a key: name.map((data, index) =>...

Answer (score 0):

In React you can use reuse your Javascript knowledge and that is really powerful. [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the function all you need.

This would also work:

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

const App = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>

      {data.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item}>
          <td>{item}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return(
  <table>
    {name.map((it, index)=> 
      <tr key={index}>
        <td> <span> {index+1} <span/> {it} </td>
      </tr>
    } 
  </table>
)
```

Comment: Did you mean `<span>{index + 1}<span>`?, if yes, please edit your answer.